# Audio inside svg element d3 map not playing

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 concept map graph that is being generated based on a JSON file. I have modified some other code I found online but I'm having a hard time navigating it and figuring out where to put things. To see my version live go here:

http://melijimenez.com/fdm177/public/index.php

If you click on an item you get a circle node that either corresponds to an item or a category. I would like if the item is a ditem, to have a Play button that an user can click on to play the audio. "Not forget my community" there would be a play button that I can click that would play the clip corresponding to that node.

[image]

I have succesfully added an html5 audio element to each ditem node by modifying this function

```
function b(X) {
    var X = E.selectAll(".node").data(X, u);
    var Y = X.enter().append("g").attr("transform", function(aa) {
        var Z = aa.parent ? aa.parent : {
            xOffset: 0,
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        };
        return "translate(" + Z.xOffset + ",0)rotate(" + (Z.x - 90) + ")translate(" + Z.y + ")"
    }).attr("class", "node").on("mouseover", g).on("mouseout", n).on("click", G);
    Y.append("circle").attr("r", 0).attr("fill", "#fff");
    Y.append("text").attr("font-size", 0).attr("class", "label");
    Y.append("audio").attr("id", "clip").attr("type","audio/mpeg").attr("src", function(jsonItem) {
        return jsonItem.audio_loc
    });

    /**Y.append("audio").attr("id","clip").append("source").attr("src", function(jsonItem) {
        return jsonItem.audio_loc
    });**/
    X.transition().duration(w).ease(F).attr("transform", function(Z) {
        if (Z === L.node) {
            return null
        }
        var aa = Z.isGroup ? Z.y + (7 + Z.count) : Z.y;
        return "translate(" + Z.xOffset + ",0)rotate(" + (Z.x - 90) + ")translate(" + aa + ")"
    });
    X.selectAll("circle").transition().duration(w).ease(F).attr("r", function(Z) {
        if (Z == L.node) {
            return 100
        } else {
            if (Z.isGroup) {
                return 7 + Z.count
            } else {
                return 4.5
            }
        }
    });
    X.selectAll("text").transition().duration(w).ease(F).attr("dy", ".3em").attr("font-size", function(Z) {
        if (Z.depth === 0) {
            return 10
        } else {
            return 15
        }
    }).text(function(Z) {
        return Z.name
    }).attr("text-anchor", function(Z) {
        if (Z === L.node || Z.isGroup) {
            return "middle"
        }
        return Z.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"
    }).attr("transform", function(Z) {
        if (Z === L.node) {
            return null
        } else {
            if (Z.isGroup) {
                return Z.x > 180 ? "rotate(180)" : null
            }
        }
        return Z.x < 180 ? "translate(" + t + ")" : "rotate(180)translate(-" + t + ")"
    });
    X.selectAll("text.label-stroke").attr("display", function(Z) {
        return Z.depth === 1 ? "block" : "none"
    });
    X.exit().remove()
}
```

I also modified the onclick function to play the audio when the node is clicked:

```
if (Y.type === "ditem") {
            clip = $("#clip")[0];
            console.log("node has been clicked")
            if (clip.paused == false) {
                clip.pause();
                alert('clip paused');
            } else {
                clip.play();
                alert('clip playing');
            }
            //window.location.href = "/" + Y.slug;
            return
        }
```

On click of the node this yields the console message "node has been clicked". However for the audio to start playing I'm getting:

```
concept-map.js:595 Uncaught TypeError: clip.play is not a function
    at SVGGElement.G (concept-map.js:595)
    at SVGGElement.__onclick (d3.js:1)
```

Here is the full code: http://melijimenez.com/fdm177/public/js/concept-map.js

Thank you so much!!

PS: I have posted another question regarding this map, but since the issues I'm posting about are different and unrelated, I thought I'd make a separate post for this particular inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

`play()` is not a jQuery function but a function of the DOM element. You therefore need to call it upon the DOM element. So try the following:

`clip = document.getElementById('clip')`

and then call `play()` on `clip`.

Going the non JQuery way here will be much more simpler.